# How do I make a clickable UIButton with animated alpha?

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-animation, uibutton

I’d like to create an `UIButton` that “breathes”, changes its alpha from 1.0 to 0.7 and back again, repeating. The code is quite simple, but when the animation runs, the button is not clickable. Which is a pity, for a button. I can understand why the button might not be clickable when the animation changes its position, but changing alpha seems quite harmless to me. Is there a way to make the button clickable, keeping the animation and not animating by hand?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use opacity.

```
UIButton *btnTest = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btnTest.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
[btnTest setTitle:@"Breathe" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnTest addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btnTest];

CABasicAnimation *fadeAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"]; 
fadeAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.7];
fadeAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];   
fadeAnimation.duration=1.0;
fadeAnimation.repeatCount=INFINITY;
fadeAnimation.autoreverses=YES;

[btnTest.layer addAnimation:fadeAnimation forKey:@"fadeInOut"];
```

Comment: Perfect, this works. I tried to animate the layer instead of the button before, but I was looking for an `alpha` property and overlooked the `opacity`. Either way, it does not work with the implicit animations, you have to attach the animation directly to the layer for the button to work. Thank you!

Comment: It works like a magic. Thanks, but hot to stop the animation?

Comment: To stop the animation, call `[btnTest.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"fadeInOut"];`. To stop all animations on the view, use `[btnTest.layer removeAllAnimations];`.